# Duplicate array in JSON from PHP code

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have the following excerpt of my PHP code (web service to deliver JSON from MySql DB). I am getting a duplicate array (square brackets) in my JSON response and I'm battling with the logic of how to get rid of ONE unnecessary array. I see there's two "array_push" but I'm not sure how to manipulate it. I am weaker on constructing arrays, but learning still.

```
//prepare response for jsonArray type
$logdetail = array();

while ($row_result = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $row_array["timeStamp"] = $row_result["manualLog_timeStamp"];
    $row_array["type"] = $row_result["manualLog_type"];
    $row_array["value"] = $row_result["manualLog_value"];

    array_push($logdetail,$row_array);
}

// success
$response["success"] = 1;

// user device node
$response["logdetail"] = array();

array_push($response["logdetail"], $logdetail);

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
```

The JSON response I get from the above is as follows (notice the unnecessary extra square/array brackets):

```
{"success":1,"logdetail":[[{"timeStamp":"2015-12-17 17:35:34","type":"w","value":"1000"},{"timeStamp":"2015-12-18 08:15:12","type":"w","value":"1200"},{"timeStamp":"2015-12-18 10:13:15","type":"w","value":"1300"}]]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
$response["logdetail"] = array();
array_push($response["logdetail"], $logdetail);
```

use

```
$response["logdetail"] = $logdetail;
```

or... manipulate the response array "directly"

```
//prepare response for jsonArray type
$response["logdetail"] = array();
while ($row_result = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $response["logdetail"][] = array(
        "timeStamp" => $row_result["manualLog_timeStamp"],
        "type" => $row_result["manualLog_type"],
        "value" => $row_result["manualLog_value"]
    );
}
// success
$response["success"] = 1;

echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: Thank you Volker! It worked. I knew it was a simple solution, just wasn't sure of it and I didn't try that. It makes complete sense to me now. Also thanks for the alternate method too.